# User Placement Rotation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that assigns users "Q", "W", "E", and "R" to a different queue position (columns "A", "B", "C", "D") after each iteration of a task. I've tried to solve this manually (using different combinations) and can't, so I'm obviously having a conceptual issue (or no ideal solution is possible given my constraints). Any help/hints are appreciated. If you do have suggestions in code, feel free to use any language.

Thank you!

I have a few constraints:

- Users (Q, W, E, R) shift every iteration.
- User in column "D" cannot be placed in column "A" in the next
  iteration.
- User "E" cannot be placed in column "A".
- Users "Q", "W", and "R" should have as equal as possible distribution
  in all columns (Meaning that, for example, user "Q" should not be in
  any one column a significantly greater number of times than users "W"
  and "R").

  ```
       A     B     C     D
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I think this works?

```
        A     B     C     D

     1  Q     W     R     E
     2  R     Q     E     W
     3  Q     E     W     R
     4  W     R     Q     E
     5  Q     W     E     R
     6  W     E     R     Q
     7  R     Q     W     E
     8  W     R     E     Q
     9  R     E     Q     W
    10  Q     W     R     E (repeats from 1 on)
```

I got here by first creating three rows rotating Q, W, and R.

```
QWR
WRQ
RQW
```

Then put those three rows three times below each other, inserting E once in column D, once in column C and one in column B.

```
QWRE
WRQE
RQWE

QWER
WREQ
RQEW

QEWR
WERQ
REQW
```

Then finally manually shuffle those nine rows till they meet the first two demands.

Comment: It looks like this works! Thanks for explaining the method. I definitely was having trouble making the mental process leap to get to this solution. Really appreciate it.